# How can i match fields with wildcards using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON object of the following form:

```
{
  "Task11c-0-20181209-12:59:30-65611" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "configname" : "Task11c",
      "datetime" : "20181209-12:59:30",
      "experiment" : "Task11c",
      "inifile" : "lab1.ini",
      "iterationvars" : "",
      "iterationvarsf" : "",
      "measurement" : "",
      "network" : "Manhattan1_1C",
      "processid" : "65611",
      "repetition" : "0",
      "replication" : "#0",
      "resultdir" : "results",
      "runnumber" : "0",
      "seedset" : "0"
    },
    ......
  },
  ......
  "Task11b-12-20181209-13:03:17-65612" : {
    ....
    .... 
  },
  .......
}
```

I reported only the first part, but in general I have many other sub-objects which match a string like `Task11c-0-20181209-12:59:30-65611`. They all have in common the initial word `Task`. I want to extract the `processid` from each sub-object. I'm trying to use a wildcard like in bash, but it seems not to be possible.

I also read about the [match()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) function, but it works with strings and not json objects.

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Filter keys that start with `Test` and get only the attribute of your choice using the `select()` expression

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select(.key|startswith("Task")).value.attributes.processid' json
```